# Bounding a partial sum with Möbius inversion formula

Tags: prime-numbers, mobius-transformation, mobius-function, mobius-inversion

I am trying to bound the partial sum $$S(n)=\sum_{k=1}^{\sqrt{n}} \mu(k) \pi\left(\frac{n}{k}\right)$$

Where $\pi(x)$ is the prime counting function, and $\mu(x)$ is the Möbius function.

Empirical results yield that the value of this partial sum is $O(\sqrt{n})$, so I suspect that there could be an application of Möbius inversion formula that could work. However, I have not been able to find such an application.

Then, my question is: is there an application of Möbius inversion formula that could work to bound $S(n)$?

**EDIT**

I have a possible application, but I am unsure if it is correct (please provide any feedback you want).

Let $$\pi(n)=\sum_{1\leq x\leq \sqrt{n}} F\left(\frac{n}{x}\right)$$

An application of the Prime Number Theorem, and the fact that $$\log(\sqrt{n})<\sum_{1\leq x \leq \sqrt{n}} \frac{1}{x}<\log(\sqrt{n})+1$$ yields that $$F\left(\frac{n}{x}\right)\approx\frac{n}{x} \frac {1}{2\log^2(\sqrt{n})}$$ Therefore, we have that $$F(n)=\sum_{k=1}^{\sqrt{n}}\mu(k) \pi\left(\frac{n}{k}\right)\approx\frac {n}{2\log^2(\sqrt{n})} $$

Comment: What is the connection between  F and S?

Comment: @BobDobbs I have just applied what is said in [Generalizations of Möbius inversion formula](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_inversion_formula), setting $G(x)=\pi(x)$ and finding the appropriate value of $F\left(\frac{n}{k}\right)$ to allow us an application of the inversion formula. Then, as I understand it, we have that $F(n)=S(n)$, and as we know the value of $F(n)$ we can bound $S(n)$. As stated in the OP, I am unsure if this is valid, so if it is wrong I will appreciate to know what a valid application of the inversion formula would be.

Comment: I don't think the Möbius inversion formula holds when you replace $n$ with $\sqrt{n}$ in the sum upper limit. For example this would imply that inversion of your formula for $S(n)$ leads to $\pi(n)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\sqrt{n}} S\left(\frac{n}{k}\right)$ which is not true for all values of $n$ (the first exception is at $n=8$).